# Time doesn't update in C

Tags: c, date, time

I've encountered a very weird problem. My time isn't changing at all, and it's always printing the same time to log file. Here is a function that overwrites the last time, and should return the new one:

```
char * update_time(char *date)
{
    time_t timer;
    timer = time(&timer);
    struct tm* time_real;
    time_real = localtime(&timer);
    date = asctime(time_real);
    strftime(date, 26, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S", time_real);
    return date;
}
```

Here is how i call the function to get new time:

```
date = update_time(date);
```

In main function i declare a pointer to char like this:

```
char *date = NULL;
```

and call the function everytime i need to get new data. What's more interesting is the fact, that when i debug my program line-by-line, i see that debugger "see" the new value of char *data, but it cannot be seen (printed) in the result file.

FIY here is the output txt file:

```
2015.04.16 20:09:49:09S Program starts
2015.04.16 20:09:49:09S Opening file: a.txt
2015.04.16 20:09:49:09S New data retrieved
2015.04.16 20:09:49:09S Closing file: a.txt
2015.04.16 20:09:49:09S End of program
```

Thanks for help in advance

**EDIT**

Gave my program a nap with Sleep(5000), and @nos and @Weather Vane were right, its all about elapsed time (what's more funny in the context of my question :D). We can close this ticket, thanks everyone for help.

Comment: So that means your program completes in less than 1/100 second? Can you please post a minimal compilable program that demonstrates the error?

Comment: You probably shouldn't overwrite the value you get back from `asctime`.  That line looks redunant.

Comment: Why are you passing date as a pointer to the function, and returning the pointer to date from the function?  That's super confusing.

Comment: at least `date = asctime(time_real);` is redundant because date is overwritten again by `strftime`.

Comment: Indeed, try reading a very large file or loop over it. The code seems fine. so Weather Vane's question is worth investigating.

Comment: @BrianCain thanks for fast reply, when i delete this line i get an assertion

Comment: time() gives you 1 second resolution, are you certain your program takes more than 1 second to complete ? (And if you're in a debugger, you probably pause execution for more than 1 second, in which case the time will change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: `asctime` is noted in a MSVC example to be deprecated since it uses an internal static array.

Consider using `asctime_s` instead, which takes a buffer argument for its output.

If you use `asctime`, you must copy its result before you use it again. It's no use remembering the returned pointer beyond its immediate use.

**UPDATE**

I can see a bug:

```
date = asctime(time_real);                          // overwrites the pointer you passed 
trftimse(date, 26, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S", time_real); // passes the pointer provided by asctime
return date;                                        // that's NOT the arg you passed
```

So the function uses the pointer to the static internal string returned by `asctime`, not the one you provided.

Your question shows this

```
char *date = NULL;
date = update_time(date);
```

So you are passing a `NULL` pointer to `strftime`. It worked before, because the irrelevant call to `asctime` replaced the `NULL` pointer with its internal static pointer.

But even when it's all correct, if the program runs and completes in a short time span, the granularity of `time` means that small time differences cannot be reported.

Comment: "`asctime` is deprecated" -- by whom?

Comment: @KeithThompson by MSVC - although it was only a comment in their example. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kys1801b.aspx

Comment: The `asctime` function is defined by the ISO C standard, and ISO has not deprecated it. There are good reasons not to use it -- both its use of a static buffer and it's weird output format. `asctime_s` is less portable; it wasn't introduced until ISO C11, as part of a new *optional* bounds-checking interface.

Comment: @KeithThompson would the same apply to `strtok` and others too?

Comment: @KeithThompson *"There are good reasons not to use it"* so presumably it is deprecated by you.

Comment: Typically the word "deprecated" has a specific meaning beyond personal disapproval. Actually the C standard uses the word "obsolescent" for this kind of thing, such as old-style non-prototype function declarations. IMHO your first sentence implies something official. Incidentally, you probably didn't intend "But" to be the last word of your answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane So what is your proposal? My intention was to overwrite the old date with new one without additional variables. Now ive added a new char pointer which made the exact same thing like with the char pointer im passing to function.

Comment: Well ive got the reason, thanks. The reason is time. Program runs so fast that i couldnt see the time difference. Thanks a lot for directing me to the right answer.

Comment: @tdbr *what is my proposal?* (1) remove `date = asctime(time_real);` (2) print the results as you get them, or (3) make an array of `time()` values and convert/print them later.

Comment: can't remove cause it calls an assertion then.

Comment: @tdbr I finally spotted it: see last sentence of revised answer.

Comment: that's it. Marked as correct now, but pls add an info about time too cause its most relevant